Trouble in Deserializing from a JSON String(which contains special characters) in C#
I have the following JSON in C# :
 string extractedText = "   [
      {
        "mainQuestion": "Question 5: Attempt Any 2 [5 x 2 = 10]",
        "question": "Write a C program to define a structure called student that contains the following members: name, age, and marks. Then, create an array of students and print the details of all students.",
        "marks": "5",
        "correctAnswer": "To solve this problem, we can define a structure called `student` that contains three members: `name`, `age`, and `marks`. Then, we can create an array of students and use a loop to print the details of each student. Here is an example program that demonstrates how this can be done:",
        "example": `
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    // Define the student structure
    struct student {
        char name[50];
        int age;
        float marks;
    };
    
    // Create an array of students
    struct student students[3];
    
    // Get the details of each student from the user
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Enter the name of student %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", students[i].name);
    
        printf("Enter the age of student %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &students[i].age);
    
        printf("Enter the marks of student %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &students[i].marks);
    }
    
    // Print the details of all students
    printf("\nDetails of all students:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\nStudent %d:\n", i + 1);
        printf("Name: %s\n", students[i].name);
        printf("Age: %d\n", students[i].age);
        printf("Marks: %.2f\n", students[i].marks);
    }
    `
      }
    ]"

I have created a class as follows :
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    public string mainQuestion { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string marks { get; set; }
    public string correctAnswer { get; set; }
    public string example { get; set; }
}
var questionsandAnswers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionAnswer>(extractedText);

As you can see, I am trying to Deserialize.I have gone through this and this but in my case its not working because as you can see there are lot of special characters in the example property which are causing me a lot of trouble to Deserialize. I have tried to replace the  backtick(just after the example property starts and also at the end) with \" and "" but nothing seems to work. I keep getting errors.
What else should I do to Deserialize the above string ?
Thanks a lot.

That's not JSON at all, and the syntax highlighting is telling you so. You can't just append strings with double quotes to create JSON. This won't even compile. You can't use arbitrary characters like ` instead of the double-quote delimiter

How was this string created? Even if it comes from a text file, it's not JSON. No JSON library would ever produce this. You can't fix this with simple replacements either. Even after fixing "example": \`` you'd have no safe way of guessing whether a double quote is part of the C code or a JSON delimiter. You could perhaps treat this as just text and extract everything between the `ticks into a separate string. Deserialize the cleaned text into aQuestionAnswerobject and *then* assign the extracted string toexample`.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the reply. This string was returned by VertexAI of google based on a input prompt. I am using the text-bison model for the same.

^^ What creates this "alleged" JSON string? It would probably need to be fixed, so the example property value is escaped. I personally would probably base64 that string just to be safe.

@PanagiotisKanavos I will work on your suggestion and will update here. Thanks

@SM and that's why you should never use statistical text generators instead of trying to understand and solve the real problem.

@PanagiotisKanavos At the moment I have no option but to use text generators.  I have written a little code to extract it. Still figuring out better ways though. Thanks.

No, you can read the docs. Even Wikipedia's entry on JSON would help you avoid this problem. Reading the docs is a lot faster than trying at random and helps you write better prompts. ChatGPT and all such tools generate text based on your prompts. They know nothing about anything. If your prompt uses the correct terms and is specific, the answer is a lot better

Yes. I am improving the prompt. Thanks for the help.

I have found a dirty solution at the moment. This is how it looks :
 string strMark = ""; string line = "";
 bool isExmapleFound = false;
 using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(responceText))
 {
     while ((strMark = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         if(isExmapleFound)
         {
             string[] lineStrings = strMark.Split(" ");
             for (int i = 0; i < lineStrings.Length; i++)
             {
                 line += lineStrings[i] + " ";
             }
             continue;
         }

         if(strMark.Contains("\"example\":"))
         {
             isExmapleFound = true;
             continue;   
         }
     }
 }

The above does extract the "example" property but since its a code, I have to write a separate code to make it look like a code(I mean I have to format it). Also, I have to write additional code to extract the remaining properties as well using the same style. I am still figuring out if i can find better solution. If anybody has, please let me know. Thanks.

Why not fix whatever produces this bad text? This is no solution and will break the moment the C code tries to use a backtick

BTW this is slow too. A faster option would be to read the entire string in memory and use a regular expression to find anything that matches \.*``, extract the match and replace it with an empty string. But again, this is a lot more work than fixing the code that produces this text
